# Run server side function on anchor tag click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to track when a file link is clicked on so I built a server side function that writes to a SQL DB when an anchor tag is clicked. It's not firing or opening the file. Here is my code:

### HTML

```
<a href="pdf/Access2013.pdf#zoom=100" runat="server" onServerClick="AccessFile_Click" target="_blank"><img src="img/pdf_icon.png" border="0" /></a>
```

### SERVER CODE

```
protected void AccessFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  App_Code.bi.LogFileDownload("Access File", Session["UserID"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: can you show the client side code as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an asp.net **LinkButton** instead:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MyLink" runat="server" OnClick="AccessFile_Click" Text="Click Here"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx

**EDIT**: I notice that you also want this to open in a new window. To do that with a LinkButton, see this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1154673.aspx/1

Basically, you need to add the following to the server-side event handler:

```
string newWindowUrl = "pdf/Access2013.pdf#zoom=100";   
 string javaScript =
  "<script type='text/javascript'>\n" +
  "<!--\n" +
  "window.open('" + newWindowUrl + "');\n" +
  "// -->\n" +
  "</script>\n";
 this.RegisterStartupScript("", javaScript);
```

Comment: I tried the above but my linkbutton is not firing the click event, here is the code:

Comment: protected void AccessFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            App_Code.bi.LogFileDownload("Access Fact Sheet", Session["UserID"].ToString());
        
        }

Comment: what is the advantage of doing this? Instead of having a plain old html anchor with the src attr populated with the path you have there. I'm kinda struggling my way around this framework and this type of solutions really seem unecessarily complicated. How would this be seen by a crawler? I gues it won't.